# Is a molotov cocktail a grenade?

Tags: fallout-4

Got lots of molotov cocktails that I use often, and want to get the Demolitions Expert perk so they do more damage, but is a molotov cocktail a grenade or no?

Comment: Love this title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, in Fallout 4, Molotov cocktails are considered grenades.

From the [wikia page on Molotov cocktails](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Molotov_cocktail_(Fallout_4)), the related perks are listed as:

> Demolition Expert, Bloody Mess, SCAV! - Cautionary Crafts

Additionally, Molotov cocktails are listed under the Explosives tab of the [Fallout 4 weapons wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_weapons#Explosives).

Comment: lol seriously still beast mode - you are about to pass me !  keep it up :D

Answer (score 4):

Demo expert will increase molotov damage. Demo expert works with all explosives and a molotov is an explosive.There is some info on a wiki page about it.http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Molotov_cocktail_(Fallout_4)